# Magento admin controller gives 404

Tags: magento

From the instructions at [Alan's blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers), I have added the router in my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Clean_Integration>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Clean_Integration>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <wellnesscoach_app_redirect>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Clean_Integration</module>
                    <frontName>appsync</frontName>
                </args>
            </wellnesscoach_app_redirect>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

And then I have my controller defined here `app/code/local/Clean/Integration/Controllers/IndexController.php` :

```
<?php

die('checkpoint1');

class Clean_Integration_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->_redirectUrl('/appointments/sync/backend/');
        die('checkpoint2');
    }
}
```

When I try to open this url, it goes to the frontend side and throws a 404.

What's causing magento to not pick up this admin router?

Comment: What's the integration like? It looks like you are redirecting to a separate application?

Comment: @benmarks Couldn't add an external link in the top menu, so redirecting it via an admin controller.

Comment: Oh, I see. That *is* a limitation. This **could** be handled with only *config.xml* and *system.xml* I think.

Comment: @benmarks Instead of `<action>`, there was a `<url>` node working which was accepting relative urls, but after upgrade to the latest EE, that stopped working, so had to do it this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
      <Clean_Integration>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
      </Clean_Integration>
  </modules>
  <admin>
    <routers>
        <integration>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Clean_Integration</module>
                <frontName>appsync</frontName>
            </args>
        </integration>
    </routers>
  </admin>
```

Should be lower case `controllers`

app/code/local/Clean/Integration/controllers/IndexController.php

You may also want to put this in Adminhtml folder so that you dont run into issue in the future if you want to add a `frontend` and a `admin` controller.

app/code/local/Clean/Integration/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php

Comment: Taking this approach, remember that all URLs for your module will need subfolder, e.g. `site.com/appsync/adminhtml_controller/action`

Comment: Thanks! `c` instead of `C` was the mistake here but I fail to understand the edge case you are trying to tell me about. And I don't see any difference in the XML you posted above in the answer.

Comment: If's not a error but more of a better practice (in my opinion),  because of the way magento create one big xml, if you have two module with the same tagname then features just stop work, so I always keep the xml tags name the same as custom module to prevent conflict. I learn this the hard way it took me over 4 hrs to figureout

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I see you made is putting the controller in a folder called 'Controllers' instead of 'controllers' (case mistake).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference to anyone else with this problem:

If your controller does **not** use the standard name of `IndexController.php`, you will still need to name both the *file* name and the *class* name within using the `...Controller` convention.

So, if your controller lives in the *Adminhtml* folder, name it `ExtensionController.php` and name the class within `My_Module_Adminhtml_ExtensionController extends ...`

Credit to goes to [this excellent article](http://twincreations.co.uk/magento-admin-routers-404-error-the-ultimate-fix/). HTH.